# Adding other android projects to my eclipse project, using maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-gradle-plugin

Most of the times a 3rd party library comes in a main directory that contains readme/setting files/build.gradle and also one directory that represents the api itself and another one is an example.

I want to add a library to my project in Eclipse, how do I do it in the best way?

The way I know is:

"import" android project to workspace, and then go to my project "properties" -> android and add a library.

I find this way odd and I frequently get weird behaviour from eclipse. Also sometimes even after importing the 3rd parry library I still can't add it (it doesn't find it). So how do I do it properly?

If the library is available in Maven Central how do I add it to my build.gradle file? I can't seem to find it in my project (I've installed Gradle plugin for Eclipse).

Comment: Did you try adding a line like `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'` to your `dependencies` section of the build.gradle file?

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend moving to Android Studio instead of Eclipse.  It has very good built-in gradle integration.